# dataset empty rows after updating

Tags: c#, mysql, dataset, rows

I'm filling gridview from mysql table

```
   public void Init()
   {    

       DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
       dataset = FillGrid();
       bindingSorce.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0];
       gridControl1.DataSource = bindingSorce;
   }

      public static DataSet FillGrid()
    {
        MySqlConnection newConnection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString);
        try
        {
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            newConnection.Open();
            if (newConnection.State.ToString() == "Open")
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = newConnection;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM main";
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(dataset);

            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
            newConnection.Close();
            return dataset;
        }
        catch { return null; }
      }
```

After any changes I'm trying to update mysql table

```
    private void gridView1_RowUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)gridView1.DataSource;
            DataTable changes = ((DataTable)bs.DataSource).GetChanges();       

            if (changes != null)
            {
                bool asd = UpdateGrid(changes);
                ((DataTable)((BindingSource)gridView1.DataSource).DataSource).AcceptChanges();
            }

        }
        catch { }

    }

    public static bool UpdateGrid(DataTable datatable)
    {
        MySqlConnection newConnection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString);
        //try
        {
            newConnection.Open();
            if (newConnection.State.ToString() == "Open")
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = newConnection;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM main";
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                MySqlCommandBuilder cmb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

                //adapter.UpdateCommand = cmb.GetUpdateCommand();
                //adapter.Update(datatable);

                cmb.GetUpdateCommand();
                adapter.Update(datatable);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            newConnection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        // catch { return false; }
    }
```

And table realy updating, but if after that I'll call Init() then FillGrid() will return dataset with right columns, but without rows!(dataset.tables[0].Rows.count = 0). After restart programm filling will work true, but again updating will have the same effect

Comment: Catching exceptions using `try...catch` would be a good idea, if you'll handle every exceptions in the `catch` part. With your presented code, errors will be ignored. And I think that's bad ass =)

Answer (score 0):

I started facing the same issue you post here after upgrading the version of MySQL database.

I have developed a C# application that querys a MySQL database and fills several datagrids using `MySqlDataAdapter` `Fill()` method. The database version in development environment was `MySQL Server 5.1.38`. When I installed the final database in the server, I used the latest release of the same version, `MySQL Server 5.1.73`.

When I started testing the application, I started getting exactly the same problem: whenever any change on the data was made via the datagrid, the database updated correctly, but after that, any datagrid in the application querying the database returned 0 rows. After searching on the web I found only two or three posts refering to the same issue, but with no answer. By now, the only way to get rid of it was uninstalling the upgrade `5.1.73` and installing the `5.1.38` version again.